# Kohana 3.1 equivalent of Request::instance()->directory?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Have this bit of code in my app...

```
Request::instance()->directory
```

After upgrading to 3.1 it stopped working... I was wondering what the 3.1 equivalent of this would be...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Request::initial()->directory()
```

Comment: ohh... was missing the () after directory... I had tried this and ::current() but it kept failing didn't know directory had become a method...

Answer (score 2):

`Request::instance()` has been replaced by `Request::current()` and `Request::initial().` Normally you'll want to use `Request::current(),` but if you are sure you want the original request (when running hmvc requests), use `Request::initial().`